# getting low accruacy than the gridsearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm runing gridsearchCV fro sklearn to try to find the best model parameters using this code.

```
modelDNN= KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_DNN_model, epochs=700, verbose=2)
hiden1=[16,32,64,128,256]
hiden2=[16,32,64,128,256]
hiden3=[16,32,64,128,256]
opt=['SGD', 'RMSprop','Adam']
drop=[0.0,0.2,0.3,0.4]
start = time.time()
param_gridDNN = dict(hiden1=hiden1,hiden2=hiden2,hiden3=hiden3,opt=opt,drop=drop)
gridDNN = GridSearchCV(estimator=modelDNN, param_grid=param_gridDNN, n_jobs=-1, cv=ShuffleSplit(1, test_size=0.2, random_state=584),scoring=R2_scorer(),verbose=2)
k.clear_session()
grid_resultDNN = gridDNN.fit(xtrain,ytrain,epochs=700 , validation_data=(xtest, ytest),verbose=2)
```

the gridsearch best result was this

```
Best: 0.840487 using {'drop': 0.4, 'hiden1': 64, 'hiden2': 32, 'hiden3': 128, 'opt': 'Adam'}
```

but I can't reach this R2 accruacy at all
trying:

```
p=gridCNN.best_estimator_.predict(xtest)
r2_score(np.asarray(ytest).ravel(), p)
```

I get 0.4696 and runing it on the train data I get 0.7521:

```
    p=gridDNN.best_estimator_.predict(xtrain)
    r2_score(np.asarray(ytrain).ravel(), p)
```

I tried also to rebuild a model with the same parameters:

```
def build_DNN_final_model():
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Dense(2,input_shape=(2,)))
 model.add(Dense(64,activation="relu"))
 model.add(Dense(32,activation="relu"))
 model.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
 model.add(Dropout(0.4))
 model.add(Dense(1,activation="linear"))
 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'] )
 return model
```

after training i got this R2 score  0.6764
So my question is what is the  0.8404 accruacy? and how can I reach the accruacy of the gridserachCV (0.8404) noting that I eliminated the cross validation using this during the grid search:

```
cv=ShuffleSplit(1, test_size=0.2, random_state=584)
```

and thank you in advance

Comment: Isn't this more of a statistics/machine learning question than a programming one?

Comment: actually the gridsearch reach this accruacy before. So I'm asking about a programming way to retrive or reach again this accruacy!

Comment: Right, but do you any have evidence which indicates that this is a programming error/bug/issue, rather than a problem with the machine learning itself?

Comment: I don't know its just an intuition that it is a programming problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using 700 epochs is the reason
you are using the best params to train your neural network but it's overtrained and shows the overfitted result
I think using an early stop condition makes it be close to 0.84

try:

```
keras.callbacks.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='auto', restore_best_weights=True)
```

you can see all callbacks here:
[keras.callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/)

If it doesn't work let me know